# How to use packages.ubuntu.com like apt-file search for different releases?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

I'd like to use the power of http://packages.ubuntu.com/ from the command line in a similar way `apt-file search -i` works to find the packages providing a file containing a specific pattern.

I cannot use `apt-file` because I need to do the search not only for the release I'm running (14.04) but also 14.10 and 15.04.

How can I get for example all the packages providing glib-2.0 schemas containing `com.canonical.Unity` but for 14.10 if I'm running 14.04 from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. install `html2text`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install html2text
   ```
2. paste the following function in your `.bashrc`:

   ```
   apt-file-remote()
   {
       pattern="$1"
       release="$2"
       if [ -z "$release" ]; then
           release="$(lsb_release -c -s)"
       fi
       wget "http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=$pattern&mode=filename&suite=$release" -qO- |
       html2text -width 999 | grep --color=never '^/'
   }
   ```
3. Restart your shell or open a new terminal

Run it with the pattern as first argument then the release code name (optional, default is current release):

```
$ apt-file-remote com.canonical.unity utopic
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/com.canonical.Unity.Greeter.Broadcast.conf                 unity-greeter-session-broadcast
[...]
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Thumbnailer.gschema.xml         thumbnailer-service
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml                     unity-schemas
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml             unity-greeter
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-gtk-module.gschema.xml          unity-gtk-module-common
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity.clickscope.gschema.xml          unity-scope-click
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity.webapps.gschema.xml             unity-webapps-service
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.canonical.unity.webapps.pkla   unity-webapps-common
```

Thanks to this function I've found that:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.Thumbnailer.gschema.xml
```

was only installed as of Utopic.

Notes:

- I use `-width 999` as by default `html2text` renders output using 80 columns which may break some names into 2 lines.
- It's actually faster than a local `apt-file search -i`

Comment: :-)  Added to `/etc/bash.bashrc`!  ;-)  (and upvoted)