# Unable to import gmpy

Tags: shared-library

I am a beginner with ubuntu and python. As I try to import `gmpy`, I get the following error:

```
import gmpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any and all help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`libgmp.so.3` is only available for 12.04, it's part of the [`libgmp3c2` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libgmp3c2/filelist).

If you're running Ubuntu 12.04, try to install the missing package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3c2
```

Note: As of 14.04, installing `python-gmpy` from Ubuntu repositories will automatically install `libgmp-dev` which provides `libgmp.so.10`.

Comment: OMG 12.04. And I asked myself why I can not find this file.

Comment: @A.B That'w why I wrote [`apt-file-remote`](http://askubuntu.com/q/595958/32239) ;)

Comment: `apt-file-remote libgmp.so.3` returns nothing o_O

Comment: @A.B. but `apt-file-remote  libgmp.so.3 precise` will return the corresponding packages

Comment: Give me the current version. GitHub?

Comment: Add a wildcard parameter for all releases =)